# Remove Halogen Cover (glass cover)

Tags: light-fixture, halogen, light-bulb

I just moved to this new place and saw that there is a halogen light that is dead. I’ve read a bunch about how to change the bulb whether this is a spring or a small gap. The question here is: how to remove the glass cover that is outside the halogen bulb. See picture attached[image]

Comment: Can we get a pic of the side view please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how this site works with upvotes for helpful answers and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the lamps I have had like that the cover simply clips in and has to be removed to change the lamp.

You can see the top clip, pull it back and lift the 1/2 round protective glass

The halogen lamp can be removed by pulling to one end, most fixtures will only flex or allow the spring load in 1 direction.

Once removed install the new lamp without touching the new lamp, finger oils can cause hot spots and cause an explosion of the new lamp.

I usually clean the shield unless installing a replacement LED then I leave the shield off as LED’s don’t explode like halogen lamps do.

Comment: The glass does not rotate unfortunately, looks like i need pliers to loosen the clips, i was able to loosen one but looks like everything is tightly fixed, I am having a hard time loosening the second one without pliers

Comment: I have never had a cover rotate usually pulling the clip allows the cover to be removed and allows access to the lamp.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the glass cover. There are two ways to access the bulb. The glass and the clip should rotate around behind the bulb to allow access to the bulb. If it's too difficult to rotate you can also carefully pull the glass cover off. The clips you see are spring-tensioned and can be pulled straight out exposing the bulb.
The bulb is spring-loaded at each end. When installing the new bulb don't touch the bulb with your bare fingers. Oil from your fingers may shorten the life of the bulb.
After replacing it, replace the protective glass cover into position.

Comment: The glass does not rotate unfortunately, looks like i need plyers to loosen the clips

Comment: No pliers needed. See edit in my answer.